# windows 8 apps forget saved credentials on close

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, facebook

Some of my windows 8 apps forget the stored credentials and preferences, facebook and lastpass apps being the most common.

Facebook for example will forget my credentials and then once logged in prompt me to update my windows profile pic etc (which I have done multiple times).

Seems to happen every time an app gets completely closed.

Cheers